# How to set priority for ResourcePool's queue in anylogic

Tags: java, resources, modeling, anylogic

I have a sequence of Services that require the same resource (a worker). I want that that the worker follows the sequence, instead of randomly choosing the service to operate. How can I set the priority of the ResourcePool's queue ? 
Thank for your time

Comment: I think you can use PriorityQueue (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). However your question is not clear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for these cases, using a service is not the right approach instead you should use a seize block in the beginning, make the agent go through all the services (which will be represented with delays now since your resource is already seized) and after your worker has done everything you can use the release block.

Remember that a service = seize + delay + release

Using a service is only justified if your worker needs to go through the sequence, but it doesn't matter what agent he's processing (which will work with Benjamin's solution)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

- create a variable "myPreviousService" of type Service in the worker. Initial value set to null
- in each service, apply the "customize resource choice" option and check that the unit to be seized has previously worked in the previous service object needed (in the screen, I set "service3" and require the worker to have worked on "service2" before)
- (only the first service will not need this requirement, obviously)
- in each service's "on seize unit", store `unit.myPreviousService = self` so the worker remembers

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, how do you create a variable of type Service? I cannot find this type in the list

Comment: Choose type "Other..." and then write "Service" in the new box